# "Install from File" not working to install addon

Tags: add-on

I'm facing a problem with the installation of a downloaded addon. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to access preferences panel in addons I select INSTALL FROM FILE

[image]

Then a choose caliper script and press INSTALL FROM FILE

[image]

After that I go back to the preferences panel and type CALIPER in search bar to find a new installed caliper addons to activate it no such addons among installed !!!

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My feeling is that something went wrong with the way you downloaded the script. Go to https://code.google.com/p/macouno/source/browse/trunk/Blender/addons/caliper.py and on the right side of the screen look for "view raw file" that's the one you want to save. The Addon should install properly now.

Comment: When an add-on doesn't install correctly, try opening the console first (Window > Toggle System Console, or on linux/mac starting blender from a terminal). When you try to install the add-on, it'll show some errors where that will help you determine the problem.

Comment: Thanks people, the problem was in saving python scripts in html format, Thx Cegaton you really helped me. After I've just copy-pasted the scrip's body into Caliper.py and saved it the installation was successful. Anyway I don't get it how to measure distances between to edges of a mesh or two object. In edit more after selectiong two edges if I apply Caliper it shows up an error. In object mode after selecting two object on apllying Caliper it draws a thick arrow with TEXT over it (instead of measuring units ) and the arrow is pointing quite different direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Archimesh installing problems](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/archimesh-installing-problems)

Comment: @user2264246 please ask your new question as a different question.

Comment: @user2264246 How in the world did you get an HTML document out of it? That's actually pretty funny! :) Glad you solved it.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136775/problems-installing-meshmachine-add-on/136822#136822

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes when you download add-ons from the internet the files are saved as HTML code and not as text files, so Blender has no way to interpret them.

The error might be caused by using the **save** otpion from the browser and not using the link on the page that triggers the download of the correct file.

To make sure your Python scripts are in the right format you can open them in a [text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_text_editors), which preferably supports python [syntax highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting).

---

#### It should look like:

[image]

#### And not like this:

[image]

---

Another common error is when the addon is contained in a .zip file instead of on a single .py file. If you unzip (or decompress) the file, you are left with a folder that contains many more files that are not easy to install manually. In such cases install directly from the .zip file instead of decompressing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with this too. I copied the text from the website and pasted it into NotePad++, but it was full of empty lines between the code lines. Blender appears to import this duff code without error, but still doesn't list it in the addons. The solution? Don't use Internet Explorer! When I opened the same code.google.com page in Chrome and copied the text, it then pastes into NotePad++ without the superfluous line spaces, and then everything works as expected within Blender.