# Installing Free Blender Resin Shader for Cycles

Tags: add-on

I have signed up to Blender Cookie and got an download link for the above mentioned file.
But when I try to install it with the addon function in Blender it won't install. Does anybody know this file and can tell me how to use it?

Regards, Pingponguin

Comment: Just like any other addon, I would assume.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13899/install-from-file-not-working-to-install-addon

Comment: If it's a shader, it's probably not an add-on. Best to contact CG Cookie for support on this.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's in the form of a node group, which is a common way to transfer node setups. But that may not be the case..