# How do I measure a distance between two points?

Tags: objects, transforms, measurement

I would like to measure the distance between the yellow points in this image:

[image]

How can I do it?

My goal is to cut the cube using the plane, but I must set a precise distance between the plane and the square's corner.

Answer (score 57):

You can use the [**Ruler/Protractor**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/editors/3dview/toolbar/measure.html). As of **Blender 2.80** the operator was renamed to [**Measure**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/editors/3dview/toolbar/measure.html) but it acts like the same way. Good news is that the *Measure* tool is now directly accessible from *3d View* as part of the main *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) and via <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> hotkey.

[image]

*Measure (Blender 2.80+) vs Ruler/Protractor (Blender 2.79)*

---

If you hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging the second marker, the cursor should snap to the **intersection point** in order to measure the correct distance. With this you can also [snap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/scene_layout/object/editing/snap.html) to the edge of the cube and **set the desired length**:

[image]

After that switch into *Edit Mode* and insert a new *Edge Loop* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) into the right spot:

[image]

**Note:** For illustration purposes I've chosen [Perspective Views](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/projections.html), but [Orthographic Views](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/projections.html) probably more useful to work with in this situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @poor, I could not find the Ruler/Protactor tool first because I had an old version of Blender. So I downloaded the last one (2.72 version) and now it works perfectly ! What a useful tool !

Comment: I have a question. If I use ctrl+click I can snap second marker on a vertex. But I don't know how I can snap first marker.

Answer (score 20):

If the section of the cut-off happens to be an isosceles triangle, you can simply use Bevel tool to "cut" precisely.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel selected edge;
- Use *Offset* as bevel type, the amount is how much you want to cut off the edge.

[image]

If both lengths are different, you may consider manually translate or slide one of them after beveling.

---

Another way to do this precisely is as follow: (I'll try to make a text version asap)

Assuming you want different offsets for both sides, one is **0.5**, another one is **0.3**:

[image]

Another related answer is worth to read:
[How to set a specific edge length numerically](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4894/696)

Comment: Nice. Simple and easy, but it only works if both sides have the same lenghts. Although 2 lengths are shown in the picture it is unclear whether they are the same.

Comment: @poor see my updates. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @LeonCheung, I'm not using the Bevel tool because my triangle isn't isoscele. The second method is very precise too and pretty straightforward. I finally used the Ruler/Protector tool and then added a difference Boolean modifier. It works fine. 
Thanks again

Comment: Not related to the question, but how do you create those gif demonstration? Is there a tool in blender to do this? I find it incredibly useful.

Comment: @Gimly Blender has a built-in screencast recorder. After that, you can pick whatever frames you want  then edit in Gimp or PS, then merge and in other GIF software. I personally use GIF Animator. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

There is an add_on called [caliper](http://www.macouno.com/commissions/caliper/) (see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13899/install-from-file-not-working-to-install-addon) on how to download and install) designed to measure things in blender. Very simple to use: it has two empties that you can position and it creates a text with the distance. Not very pretty... but useful...

[image]

Comment: The first link is broken (Google Code was shut down in January 2016).

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks for pointing that out. The link has been fixed to the current host.

Answer (score 8):

You could also do a Difference Boolean Modifier. It's fairly straight forward and useful for creating things like holes though solid geometry (windows is one good example).

The great thing here is that it can be done with a few clicks without taking into accounting measuring sides, just position the two objects as you want them to be.

Process:

1. Cube and Plane

[image: <a href="http://imgur.com/KkmuzbC"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/KkmuzbC.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>]

2. Add Boolean Modifier and change to Difference, then select the Plane as the object to Boolean the Cube with. I had to flip the normal of the plane to get it to work like you want it to.

[image]

3. Apply Modifier and hide the Plane.

[image]

4. In Edit Mode enable Edge Info on the Mesh Display section.

[image]

Note: I rarely use the Boolean Modifier until after I'm finished texturing all objects in the scene. This is because the Boolean modifier preserves the Materials and UVs from both objects. This saves me some time because I don't have to spend so much time UV mapping complex geometry and can instead work with more primitive shapes and large, simple UV islands.

Comment: This isn't really answering the question as it stands, but method here could be useful to the op in addition to a measuring tool as the the plane can be moved even after the boolean modifier is enabled

Comment: Ah, I need to read more carefully. Either way, the options given in all the responses would work splendidly. As you say, the Boolean is mostly for adjusting geometry after measurement, alongside adding extra details to models.

Comment: Thank you @FSLuaGuy, I followed this method to cut the rectangle and it works perfectly! I also measured the distance between the rectangle's corner and the plane, which was my first problem, by using the Ruler/Protactor tool.

Comment: @FSLuaGuy the links to your images have disappeared.  Please use the built in tools on this site to upload images.