# How to Punch a Hole in a Plane

Tags: mesh

I have a face that is 4 by 11 units. I want to punch a perfectly square hole in that plane, about 3 by 3 units. How do I do this?

I do not want to use any subdivision whatsoever.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/how-to-measure-a-distance-between-two-points/

Comment: No it's not. It's a flat disconnected plane.

Comment: The *ruler* is key here - you can use it for a single object as well.

Comment: I literally want to punch a hole in a single face.

Answer (score 6):

Make a plane with the dimensions you need to cut.

[image]

In *object* mode select the ***cutting object*** first then while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the ***object to be cut***.

Set your view to orhtogonal, go into edit mode, press the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type ***Knife Project***

[image]

Th [Knife Project](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html#knife-project) tool will make a hole using the shape of the selected object.

[image]