# Showing the dimensions of an object when rendering?

Tags: measurement, dimensions

In Sketchup, we can display the dimension of a specified edge as below. Is there a way to do display that in the final render in blender?

[image]

Comment: There's an addon called [measureit](https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/tree/master/measureit#changes-in-version-15) which can do this

Comment: In general geometry is required. There is also an addon called caliper, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19783/3710