# How to link a text object body to the edge length of another object with Python?

Tags: python

I would like to create a tool to measure object length dynamically.

Something like a group of 2 objects:

- 1 unique edge object
- 1 text object (children of the previous)

How to link edge length to the text object body?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/how-do-i-measure-a-distance-between-two-points

Comment: Also probably useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb1U7g4JFbA

Answer (score 0):

Dolf Veenvliet already dit it several years ago!
Thank you to Duarte who provided the link.

[The Caliper Blender Addon](http://www.macouno.com/commissions/caliper/)

[The script](https://github.com/macouno/macouno/blob/master/Blender/addons/caliper.py)