# How to calculate the distance between two selected vertices?

Tags: modeling, mesh, measurement

Now I have got a new problem. I want to measure the distance between 2 selected vertices but I do not know how to do that in Blender. Can you help me? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I measure a distance between two points?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/how-do-i-measure-a-distance-between-two-points)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use MeasureIt addon that you can enable from User Preferences (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>), Add-ons tab:

[image]

Or you could also use an inbuilt ruler that you can find in the Tool Shelf(<kbd>t</kbd> panel), Grease Pencil tab that you can snap to vertices holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while dragging:

[image]