# I'm trying to install this add-on: blender_mmd_tools

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to install this add-on: blender_mmd_tools.
I go to File/User Preferences/addons, then I click "Install add-on", but when I look to enable the add-on, it doesn't appear on the add-on list. I've already gone into scripts/addons folder, and I see the add-on in the folder, but I can't find it on the list in user preferences to enable it. How do I enable the add-on if I can't find it in the list?

Comment: make sure you downloaded the script as a python file and not as html read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13899/install-from-file-not-working-to-install-addon

Comment: By the way, I'm using a mac. The add-on appears as a folder in the scripts folder. Do I need to do anything differently? If so, tell me how I can check if the add-on is in the right format.

Comment: Contact the author of the add-on. The most likely cause is that the add-on is not compatible with your version of blender, or it's simply a mistake on their part.

Answer (score 2):

Installable.

1) Unzip the blender_mmd_tools-master.zip file you downloaded

2) Open the folder containing your Blender.app

3) Right-click Blender.app and select "Show Package Contents"

4) Then open the "Contents" folder, followed by "Resources", then "2.76" (or whatever version of Blender you may have), then "scripts", and finally open the "addons" folder

5) Now inside the "addons" folder, you want to copy and paste the "mmd_tools" folder that was unzipped from inside the blender_mmd_tools-master.zip file

6) Now open (or restart) the Blender app and go to the User Preferences and search mmd_tools and check to use the add-on and "Save User Settings"

7) Now go back to 3D view and it should be a new tab called mmd_tools

Have fun!