# How to install Mitsuba renderer?

Tags: add-on, installation, external-applications

I try to install [Mitsuba](https://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/download.html) render engine. Mitsuba comes in .zip file. After the installation process, I can not find the renderer (neither in the render section nor in *User Preferences*). What's the solution to install Mitsuba properly?

*Blender 2.77a, Windows 10 64-bit Home*

Comment: Have a look at http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install?rq=1 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13899/install-from-file-not-working-to-install-addon?rq=1 in the Related links to the right.  Can you provide a link to the Mitsuba render engine zip file.

Comment: Which OS, 32/64bit, where do we get Mitsuba, where are the installation instructions? Please explain elaborately by editing your post and adding the information ;-)

Comment: I downloaded from here https://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/ and my OS is windows 10 64-bit home. Blender 2.77 a. For your reference @batFINGER

Comment: Assuming you have https://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/repos/exporters/mitsuba-blender/archive/tip.zip from the instructions in readme.txt "Copy the 'mtsblend' folder into Blender scripts/addons directory and
then enable Mitsuba addon on 'Addons > Render' section of Blender
'User Preferences' panel."

Comment: Good read: https://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/plugins.html. Does this help?

Comment: If it doesn't work, you need to say what exactly you did, because "the installation process" is not descriptive enough.