# Add-on issues in installation

Tags: add-on

im very new to blender and for some reason im having no success installing any add-on,i followed all of the steps yet when i pick the file to be installed nothing happens.In the image this is what it gives me when i press install then it disappears and nothing.Thank you in advance :)
[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on the steps you are taking. From the screenshot it appears you are trying to install the blender_osm addon by clicking on install and choosing  the `__init__.py` file.  Which will either do nothing, or break blender. What you want to do is copy the `blender_osm` folder into your [`USER/addons`  folder](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html)  [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13899/install-from-file-not-working-to-install-addon?s=2|64.5439)

Comment: Thank you so much for you help,i tried copying the blender_osm folder into the addons file and it worked out! It appeared after refreshing the list.

Comment: Good one. Hitting F8 is another way to refresh the list. (meant to mention)

Comment: the problem was that no matter what i clicked wether it was the _init_.py file or the whole folder or the zip nothing would be installed,but after copying it into the add on file it appeared. Thank you :)

Comment: [Re zip file addons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install) Dragging the file, or  For multi-file addons, the addon's folder into blender addon folder  is my MO, rather than use install button.

Comment: Seems like that's the only way add-one will function for me.Thanks again