# I am trying to install py script in blender 2.80, but i cant find that script in user preference!

Tags: python, add-on, installation

I am trying to install python script in blender 2.80, but I cant find that script in user preference!

I have checked everything and its all set but I still cant find script to activate!

Is it because blender 2.80 unstable? if yes then how much I have to wait for blender 2.80 to support scripts?

Comment: Depends on the script but it should appear at least. What's the script/addon you are talking about?

Comment: Read: [Installing an addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1689/31447) and [“Install from File” not working to install addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13917/31447)

Comment: http://www3.telus.net/wacampbell/downloads/BlenderToMSTS.zip, its the zip which contains the addon and it worked in blender 2.79b but not in blender 2.80

Comment: *Preferences > Add-ons > Install from file* works, problem is that **the Addon needs to be updated** in order to work properly in *Blender 2.8x*.

Comment: so any idea how to update script?thanks already :)

Comment: No problem, all relevant changes: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons