# Problems installing MESHmachine Add-on

Tags: add-on

I just extracted this addon called MESHmachine in the "Blender 2.8/scripts/addons" folder and when I go to open Blender, it didn't show up on the "Preference - Add-ons" tab.

I clicked "Install Add-on from File" and tried to install the MESHmachine py. script from the "C:\Users\Khalil Poaches\Desktop\blender-2.80.0-git.009dbc2bc9fb-windows64\2.80\script\addons\MESHmachine_init_.py" onto the add-ons menu then I have to delete one of each pair to resolve the double script issue.

How can I undo this?

Comment: I install it to 2.79b and the notice is refer to documentation because there is a bug in Bender, but there seems to be no solution there. I managed to install HardOps and Decal Machine.

Answer (score 3):

1. Do **NOT extract** the zip file of a downloaded add-on **unless told otherwise in the installation instructions**!

Instead, just go to "User Preferences - Add-ons" and use the "Install Add-on from file" button. Navigate to the folder to which you downloaded the add-on, double-click on the zip file and activate the add-on.

2. Do **NOT** try to install add-ons in Blender 2.80 that aren't made specifically for Blender 2.80!

If the instructions tell you, that an add-on is not yet ready to be used in Blender 2.80, it means exactly that.*

Instead, use the Blender version that is required for the add-on to work.

**How to clean up your messed-up installation**

Exit Blender, then go to your "Blender\2.xx\scripts\addons" folder and delete the folder/script. Start Blender and check "User Preferences - Add-ons" and look for the add-on. It should be gone.

*In your case, MESHmachine does not support Blender 2.80 yet.