# Why when I try to load add-on from github which have expansion .py , then it is loaded in TXT format and I can't add it to the blender

Tags: add-on

Why when I try to load add-on from github which have expansion .py , then it is loaded in TXT format and I can't add it to the blender
I tried to put into folder scripts also

Comment: just rename the .txt to .py. Note that this is not really a question about blender but about the use of your browser and how to download files. Also, in github you have the choice to clone or download a .zip file. Zip files will keep the files with no transformation.

Comment: Related link: [“Install from File” not working to install addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13899/install-from-file-not-working-to-install-addon/13917#13917)

Comment: Also related: [Problems installing MESHmachine Add-on](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/136822/23985)

Comment: Oh, and it would be very helpful if you tell us at least the name of the add-on + (of course) what Blender version you are talking about. [This](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) might be useful.