# "One or more addons do not have UTF-8 encoding"

Tags: add-on, customization

I tried installing an addon and I'm sure I did it wrong, because now I have a warning that I didn't notice before.

[image]

The warning icon now shows up next to addons that don't seem to be related to the addon I was trying to install (BoolTool).

[image]

How can I make the warnings go away?

Comment: Does the error disappear if you add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the very top of every offending script file? You should also check whether the files start with a byte order mark (BOM). There is not supposed to be one AFAIK.

Comment: @CoDEmanX I'd really prefer not to go into each file, firstly because it takes too long and secondly because I'm afraid I'll mess more things up.

Comment: The files need to be fixed either way if their encoding is messed up. Of course the responsible add-on author should fix this if possible. Which scripts are causing this exactly?

Comment: @CoDEmanX All the messed up ones came with the Blender install and weren't broken before. Some of them are in the above screenshot and the rest are here: http://imgur.com/JcSCAjB.

Comment: But what does it say in the System console? I doubt that all of the addons in your screenshot are broken... unless some contributor messed them all up systematically (search and replace?).

Comment: @CoDEmanX Took a few attempts to get anything other than "No such file or directory", but I'm trying: http://imgur.com/UcKOQGZ
Also, this: http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/japbcvpavbzau9dbuaxf.jpg

Comment: Doesn't look like it's printing anything useful... Is this a standard 2.75 installation, or did you install any extra addons?

Comment: @CoDEmanX I installed Amaranth Toolset. I also tried to install BoolTool, but it's not showing up. All the error-ful addons are from the standaRd 2.75 installation.

Comment: That warning icon next to the addon name generally indicates that the author of the addon included a "warning" message as part of the addon (perhaps to indicate alpha status or something). It doesn't necessarily mean there's something wrong with the addon. If you reload factory settings, do you still get the encoding message?

Comment: @gandalf3 Loaded factory settings and I still get the same warnings (even though I knew they weren't there when I originally installed).

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/archimesh-installing-problems

Answer (score 3):

Even if you solve the UTF-8 Warning, the other warnings will not disappear -- but there's no reason to worry about them: *here's why:*

The warning icons to the right of those add-ons are benign and intentionally added by the authors of those add-ons to warn users about something -- but they have always been there.

It's been pointed out above, but it's worth a mention and a screenshot.

[image]

Addons can define if they should be displayed with warning icons, this is to indicate to the user that there's some remaining work to be done on the addons. The message about the UTF-8 isn't caused by something that also causes those warnings. I have them too and my Blender works fine, and those warnings don't affect any part of Blender other than to give that indication.

The fact that the UTF-8 warning uses the same icon doesn't mean that it's the cause of those warning icons on the other addons, though it's understandable that you might think so. This is merely a matter of 'icon reuse'

Take for instance the `Render: Network Render` Addon. An addon you are not likely to ever use unless you have a network. In its source code (in its `__init__.py` file) it has a short manifest which we call a `bl_info dictionary`. It looks like this:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Network Renderer",
    "author": "Martin Poirier",
    "version": (1, 8),
    "blender": (2, 60, 0),
    "location": "Render > Engine > Network Render",
    "description": "Distributed rendering for Blender",
    "warning": "Stable but still work in progress",
    "wiki_url": "http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.5/Manual/"
                "Render/Engines/Netrender",
    "category": "Render",
}
```

The `bl_info` is a way for an add-on to tell Blender 'Hey! add me to the add-on list, and display this information about me`. Without that bl_info add-ons will not appear in the add-ons list.

The inclusion of the key / value pair `"Warning":  "Stable but still work in progress"` is the sole reason you see the warning icon beside that addon in your *preferences -> Add-ons* tab. All the other addons in that list that have the warning icon, has a similar entry in their `bl_info`.

Comment: Ah, I see, I must have not noticed the other warnings before. How can I tell which one is causing the UTF-8 error?

Comment: if you start a terminal.. and from that terminal start Blender, and then keep the terminal and blender side by side.. then open the user-preferences and addons tab...navigate until you see that UTF8 warning... maybe hit the refresh at the bottom of the prefs window... I would expect some kind of messages being displayed in the terminal window... take a screenshot of those if you do get any interesting messages regarding the utf8... it might mention the addon..  or the it might show here : http://wiki.blender.org/uploads/thumb/2/22/1_2_ToolTipInfoShow.png/590px-1_2_ToolTipInfoShow.png

Comment: Managed to follow the steps you listed (yay! First time opening an application from the terminal) but didn't see any more messages. I'm going to try to install BoolTool properly and see if that helps anything.

Comment: [Installed BoolTool](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36216/how-to-install-booltool-on-a-mac), and whether by coincidence or causation, I have no more errors! Yay! Thanks for your help, @zeffii!

Comment: all credit goes to yourself for persisting!