# How can I completely remove Blender from my Mac?

Tags: installation

Rather than continue spending time on [an issue I can't resolve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35615/one-or-more-addons-do-not-have-utf-8-encoding), I want to completely wipe Blender from my computer and reinstall it as if I'm installing it for the first time.

Steps I tried:

1. I selected "Load factory settings", but Blender stayed the same.
2. I dragged the Blender folder and zip file to the trash and Securely Emptied Trash, but when I downloaded and installed a fresh version from the Blender site, Blender still had my old settings.

Still, Blender opens with all my old settings. How can I remove all traces of Blender and install it totally new?

Answer (score 3):

Check the OSX sections in the Blender manual, it lists all the default paths where Blender stores data / scripts after you install them.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html?highlight=directory

If you remove Blender from all those places, and then reinstall, you'll be ready to rock again.

__

Blender, like almost all programs, must store persistent information like preferences, themes and scripts somewhere on your hard-drive. This is information you don't want to lose when you update Blender to a newer version. Normally that's exactly what you want, but if the stored information contains some weird content ( like in your case ) you can do a purge by removing all references to Blender from the directories listed in the link above. Blender will add those directories back again if it needs to.

Comment: I get "The folder can't be found" when I copy and paste Local, User, and System lines into "Go to Folder", as shown here: http://imgur.com/koagPCX

Comment: @Aubrie, has the warning message about UTF-8 gone away?

Comment: @zeffii The link is broken.