# How to install BoolTool on a Mac?

Tags: add-on

How can I install the BoolTool?

The [instructions](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/BoolTool) lead me to [this Github site](https://github.com/vitorbalbio/code/tree/master/BoolTool) but don't tell me whether to use "BoolTool 0.1.rar - BoolTool 0.2 release" or "BoolTool 0.2 rar - BoolTool 0.2" (and those names are confusing). The instructions are also unclear in other ways. For example, "5. Save in somewhere as "BoolTool.py" if it's not"—does that mean manually change the extension to ".py"?

A step-by-step list with no assumption that I know Github or ".rar" or "Raw" or ".zip" or ".py" would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the main repository page, and click download zip.

[image]

Then extract it on your computer, and navigate to the folder it creates, and then into the BoolTool folder.

Then extract the .rar file with the largest number (these are version numbers).

Inside Blender, go the users preferences, and then to the Addons tab, and click install from file.

[image]

Navigate to the booltool folder, and enter the folder that was created from the .rar. Then click on the .py, and click install.

The BoolTool Addon should now be installed. If you want to save it into your settings, so that it's always enabled, simply click Save User Settings button.

[image]

To extract a .rar on a Mac, you can use [UnrarX](http://www.unrarx.com/).

Comment: Also note that you can download the raw file directly from github, to avoid downloading all the extra files in the repo

Comment: Thanks for the replies! How do I extract the .rar? I'm on a Mac, by the way; apologies for not mentioning it earlier.

Comment: @gandalf3 I tried doing this when setting up this answer, but I was getting a corrupted file. That's why I did it this way.

Comment: @Aubrie I'm not entirely sure how you would do it on a mac. I'm mostly just not sure about if the rar extractor is installed by default or not, or how to get to the right click menu. I'm sure that you can figure it out with five minutes worth of googling.

Comment: Sure enough, five minutes' worth of Googling revealed UnRarX (http://www.unrarx.com/). :) Posting it here in the hopes that it'll save time for others in the future. Thanks for the help, @TARDIS Maker and @gandalf3!

Comment: @Aubrie I'll save people even more time and throw it in my answer :)

Comment: tho, realistically .. it's absurd that BoolTool is a packed file in the first place... it's  a simple Python file..with a readme.